# AppCenter Build error "Provisioning profile does not include signing certificate apple push services"

Tags: ios, xamarin, visual-studio-app-center, visual-studio-app-center-distribute

When I try to build pipeline for build ipa using appcenter it gives me error :

> Provisioning profile "CloodVoteAdhoc" does not include signing certificate "Apple Push Services: com.optiknights.cloodvote"

However I have added provisioning profile that include IPhone distribution certificate and also it has app id which includeds both development and distribution apple push certificates. Still Appcenter give me error while setting up pipeline for appcenter ios build.

Please let me know if you have faced anything like this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steps to solve:

1) Open Xcode -> Project navigator -> select target -> general.
2) Select the "Automatically manage signing" under Signing
3) Select the team.
4) Under team you can see there is an "Provisional Profile Xcode Managed Profile" click the icon i. You see the provisional profile which is old one.
5) Just drag and drop into the terminal with added comment "rm".
 
6) The older provisional profile is removed automatically and new provisional profile is create by Xcode.
7) Clean and take the build.