# Visual Studio App Center Rejects Provisioning File and Signing Cert Combo

Tags: xcode, react-native, provisioning-profile, visual-studio-app-center, code-signing-certificate

I am attempting to set up an iOS build and distribution flow on Visual Studio App Center for my React Native application using the bare expo workflow. I am running into an issue where App Center rejects my iOS provisioning profile and signing certificate due to the error: "*Provisioning profile 'profile name' does not include the provided signing certificate*"

This seems like a cryptic error since I know that my provisioning profile does contain the signing certificate that I used and I have verified this in XCode. I have been able to build and sign XCode builds using manual signing with the profile and cert, but when I try to add them to the "Sign Builds" step of App Center builds I get the error mentioned above.

I have attempted to find similar issues to this on various forums and on StackOverflow, but have been unsuccessful in finding a successful solution for me. Here are links to a few of the solutions which I have tried:

- [AppCenter Build error "Provisioning profile does not include signing certificate apple push services"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55625485/appcenter-build-error-provisioning-profile-does-not-include-signing-certificate)
- https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/153425/appcenter-build-error-provisioning-profile-does-not-include-signing-certificate-apple-push-services

I would be happy to provide any further information if it is helpful.

Thanks in advance.

[Image of Error received on App Center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBVSi.png)

Answer (score 0):

problem for me was that my distribution certificate expired. so I had to create a new one and edit the provisioning profile to hook it up with the new certificate. with this set up App Center gave me the exact same error even though I was able to sign my app on my local machine with the same cert and provisioning profile.

Solution was I had to create a completely new provisioning profile instead of editing my old one.